# Android Studio 4.0.1 - Where did the "Vertical indent guide" settings go?

Tags: android, android-studio

Where did the "Vertical indent guide" settings go?
They used to be here

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General

How do I turn them on/off now in Android Studio 4?

Vertical indent guide

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the editor line area

Check the `Show Indent Guides`

[image: preview]

Or

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> `Show Indent Guides`

Comment: OK these settings are now available in the new version of Android Studio. They didn't exist before. -)